# Getting Azure DevOps repository files with PowerShell and Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-repos

Trying to see how I could make GET requests to get the content of the Postman collection files from the Azure DevOps repositories using Powershell. This is as far as I have gotten. It just returns me the page with the following:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : 
  
    Page not found.
    html {
```

The code is as follows:

```
$personalToken = "***"
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalToken)"))
$header = @{authorization="Basic $token"}
$projectUrl ="https://dev.azure.com/***/***/_git/PostmanCollections/PostmanFunctionalTest/PostmanFunctionalTest.postman_collection.json"
$content = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $projectUrl -Method GET -contentType "application/json" -Headers $header
$content
```

What is wrong here? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Rest API: [Items - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP) to get the file content of the Repo.

Here is PowerShell example:

```
$token = "PAT"

$url=" https://dev.azure.com/{ORG}/{PPROJECT}/_apis/git/repositories/{Reponame}/items?recursionLevel=0&versionDescriptor.version={Branchname}&versionDescriptor.versionOptions=0&versionDescriptor.versionType=Branch&includeContent=true&resolveLfs=true&path={filepath}&6.1-preview.1"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get  -ContentType application/json

Write-Host "$response"
```

**Update:**

```
$token = "PAT"

$url=" https://dev.azure.com/{ORG}/{PPROJECT}/_apis/git/repositories/{Reponame}/items?recursionLevel=0&versionDescriptor.version={Branchname}&versionDescriptor.versionOptions=0&versionDescriptor.versionType=Branch&includeContent=true&resolveLfs=true&path={filepath}&6.1-preview.1"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get  -ContentType application/json | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99


Write-Host "$response"
```

Comment: Alright. Thanks a lot for this. I will make this as an answer anyways. I get the content of the files in the root folder. Tried to get the files inside the folders without luck. Is this API limitation or? Thanks!

Comment: @x0nomad Based on my test, it also can get the files inside the folder. you need to set the path in the URL . for example: `path=bank1/bank1.sln`

Comment: Tried. Works great with .md and .py, but not with .json files :( Getting:

with readme.md
`PS C:\Intel\curl test> C:\Intel\curl test\test.ps1
test`

***.json
`
PS C:\Intel\curl test> C:\Intel\curl test\test.ps1
@{info=; item=System.Object[]}
`

Comment: Tested with pulling test.py with some content and it works too. Could be limitation?

PS C:\Intel\curl test> C:\Intel\curl test\test.ps1
test Python

Comment: @x0nomad Refer to my update. you need to add -Depth  parameter in the PowerShell script. Then you can get the value of JSon file

Comment: Alright. Huge thanks! :) Works perfect now!